# Running C# program through Microsoft VS results in Failed at 'ExecuteQuery with project query execution service'

Tags: c#

I have just downloaded Microsoft VS to try and learn a bit of C# following the Microsoft tutorials.

This is the exact code the lesson tells me to type
Console.WriteLine("Hello World.");
[image: my vs]

When I press the 'run project associated with this file' button in the top right, I see an error in the output box. (See image)

Not sure what to do, or if I need to install more libraries or if I just set VS up properly.

Thank you!

The only thing I did different was to put VS in administrator mode when I launch it. Nothing changed in the error.

Comment: You can't normally compile and run a standalone `.cs` file, you need, at the very least, a project (`.csproj`) file to go along with it. I would recommend getting Visual Studio Community 2022 instead of Visual Studio Code, because it has a bunch of helpful templates to get you started.

Comment: If you want to just try some code practise you can use online c# compilers.

Comment: Visual Studio and Visual Studio Code are two completely different applications.

Comment: Please include the text of the error as text within the question, not as part of a screenshot. The error reads _"Failed at 'ExecuteQuery with project query execution service' (3781ms) with error: Error: Exception while talking to proxy: Error: No project or solution is opened in the workspace."_ which states _"No project or solution is opened in the workspace."_ You cannot compile/run bare C# files. they need to part of a project or solution. Take a look at `dotnet new`